# Which are the mainly used presskeycode in appium Testing?

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I have doubt about Presskeycode used in appium. 
I can successfully used the camera,search press key code.
but i want more information about others keys.
can you give me one by one details of key code or mostly used keycodes.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look on keycode keyevents provided on Android dev site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html